# How to find last text before character x while character y is still behind y Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop

I was trying to find an elegant solution to the following problem. I have the following string :

This ) is ) some $ text. **)** lkzejflez **$** aaeea ) aeee

Existing out of a part that is human readable text before the bold marked bracket and a part that just plain rubbish after the bracket. I need to find the human readable text in string alike this one. I need to get the text before the last bracket (bold marked) that still has a dollar sign (bold marked) behind it. Here is my solution to the problem :

```js
const info = "This)is)$a sentence.)lkzejflez$aaeea)aeee";
let result;

for(let i = 0; i < info.length;i++){
  const char = info[i];
  const after = info.substring(i+1,info.length);
  const otherChance = after.indexOf(')') < after.lastIndexOf('$');
  if(otherChance){continue;};
  const isEndBracket = char ===')';
  const before = info.substring(0,i)
  if(isEndBracket){result = before;break;};
}
console.log(result)
```

The expected result is 'This)is)$a sentence.' My code does return this result but it uses substr and a forloop where regex could be used. I do however not now how. Does anyone know a more elegant solution to my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you need a regex that matches start of line to a dollar sign, and then matches to the next ) character?

Comment: @ Zach Jensz I do need a regex that matches start of a line to a dollar sign and then to the last  ) still before a dollar sign. I bassicly need a regex that  returns the text before the last ) that still has a $ behind it.

Comment: I'll write up a positive lookahead for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following regex: `^.*\)(?=.*\$)`

Explanation: Match as many characters as possible from the start of the line to the last ) that is followed by a $.

Detailed explanation: Greedily match zero or more of any character except a newline from the start of the line to a ) character that is followed by zero or more of any character except a newline and then a $ sign.

Comment: thanks man! Working just great.

Comment: Great. Look into regex lookarounds @JipHelsen they are extremely cool

Comment: Sure will! Thanks for the help.